# How are hibernate Validators integrated into spring boot starter project

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I often use constraints on fields in spring . The constraint are standard or custom

```
public  abstract class OrganizationEntity {
@Length(min = 1 , max = 256, message = "Organization name max length is 256 and min length is 1")
@NotNull(message = "Organization name should not be empty")
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$",message = "Organization name can contain Alphanumeric character and Hyphen in the middle")
public abstract String getName();
}
```

On navigating to Length or Pattern annotation I see the definition of annotation
org.hibernate.validator.constraints

```
    @Documented
@Constraint(
    validatedBy = {}
)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(List.class)
public @interface Length {
    int min() default 0;

    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    public @interface List {
        Length[] value();
    }
    }
```

I see validatedBy is left empty which implies there is somebody mechanism/library which has implementation for these checks. Which library provides these implementation? How does spring manage this validation flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate provides the validation implementation and it is used by Spring.

I may be oversimplifying, but as I understand Spring configures Hibernate's `ValidationFactory` implementation ([`ValidationFactoryImpl`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/ValidatorFactoryImpl.java)) with `Validator` and `ExecutableValidator` implementation ([`ValidatorImpl`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/ValidatorImpl.java)) for Spring's application context usage, exposes it for other Spring components and convert validation results into `BindingResult`.

At the same time, Hibernate's `ValidatorImpl` uses validation context, in which `ConstraintValidator`s are registered as a map with different annotations from package `javax.validation.constraints` as keys, along with Hibernate's own constraints, such as `@URL` and `@ISBN`. This map can be found in the [`ConstraintHelper`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/metadata/core/ConstraintHelper.java) class.

For example, you can find [`PatternValidator`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/PatternValidator.java) registered there for validating values annotated with `@Pattern`.

Then we have the next Hibernate validation flow (again - simplified):

1. `ValidatorImpl` tries to validate something and creates `MetaConstraint`s (helper class with all information needed for validation);
2. `MetaConstraint` creates `ConstraintTree` for multiple constraints check;
3. `ConstraintTree` calls `ConstraintValidatorManager` and its `getInitializedValidator` method, which returns needed `ConstraintValidator` for a specific annotation from a map, mentioned before.

So the validation framework, used by Spring, already knows which `ConstraintValidator` instances to use for specific validation annotations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the classes I needed. I am just curious to know if there is any documentation that points to how these libraries integrate with each other. I could understand from debugging that
javax.validation -> javax.validation.spi -> hibernate validator . I could also they arrive at these by looking at what is available on classpath . Would love to understand more about this